# Joining two joins in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

**Background**

I've needed to learn some PostgreSQL quickly and from scratch in order to do a data analysis project about car insurance. I have a locally stored PostgreSQL database of fairly decent size (around 8gb worth of data on insurance claims for vehicles like cars and motorcycles), and I've needed to `JOIN` and `UNION ALL` a couple of things in order to get the table I need for my statistical models.

The first part of what I've needed to do is this thing, a `JOIN` inside of a `UNION ALL` between two tables about car claims and motorcycle claims:

```
select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.service_date,
    h.principal_problem_cd,
    h.problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.auto_claims_line_items as l
JOIN claims.auto_claims_general h on l.claim_id = h.claim_id
UNION ALL
select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.entry_date as service_date,
    NULL as principal_problem_cd,
    NULL as problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.motorcycle_claims_line_items as l
```

This yields a table that looks like this (column names abbreviated for aesthetics):

```
cust_comb_id| claim_id | "Part_Cd" | svc_date | prin_prob_cd | prob_cd_vers_flg |
------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------------+------------------|
            |          |           |          |              |                  |
```

As you can see, the car claims have some columns that the motorcycle claims don't have. This is fine -- I've filled those in as `NULL` in order to get the `UNION ALL` to work. Now the car claims table is nicely stacked on top of the motorcycle claims table. So far, so good.

The second part of what I've done so far is this other thing, which concerns data about car and motorcycle insurance policyholders ("customers"):

```
select m.customer_dob,
       m.customer_id,
       m.customer_gender_cd,
       m.customer_zip_cd,
       c.customer_combined_id
from customer."Customer" m
JOIN customer.customer_combined_crosswalk c on m.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

The result of which looks like this:

```
dob | customer_id | gender_cd | zip_cd | cust_comb_id |
----+-------------+-----------+--------+--------------|
    |             |           |        |              |
```

**The Problem**

I've figured out two halves of my data manipulation, but I don't know how to put these halves together, so to speak. I want (I think) to left join these two things on `cust_comb_id`, but I'm not sure how to write it. I want to keep everything in the first part (the claim data) and bring in data from the second part (the policyholders / customers) when `cust_comb_id` matches, and give null values if it doesn't. Here's a visual of what I'm looking for:

```
cust_comb_id| claim_id | "Part_Cd" | svc_date | prin_prob_cd | prob_cd_vers_flg |dob | cust_id | gender_cd | zip_cd |
------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------------+------------------|----+---------+-----------+--------+
            |          |           |          |              |                  |    |         |           |        |
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried to use subqueries to join these joins, but I keep getting errors. **Edit**:

Here's a concrete example of something I've tried:

```
select * 
from
(select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.service_date,
    h.principal_problem_cd,
    h.problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.auto_claims_line_items as l
JOIN claims.auto_claims_general h on l.claim_id = h.claim_id
UNION ALL
select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.entry_date as service_date,
    NULL as principal_problem_cd,
    NULL as problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.motorcycle_claims_line_items as l) as cl
LEFT JOIN
select m.customer_dob,
       m.customer_id,
       m.customer_gender_cd,
       m.customer_zip_cd,
       c.customer_combined_id
from customer."Customer" m
JOIN customer.customer_combined_crosswalk c on m.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

This yields the error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"`.

Any help is much appreciated.

[Note: `customer_combined_id` and `customer_id` are two different things: the `combined id` is unique, and made to account for when a customer switches from one insurance plan - where they have one `customer_id` - to another, where they're given a new one.]

Comment: "I've tried to use subqueries to join these joins, but I keep getting errors." Show what you've tried and what kind of errors you got. Were that SQL errors or logical errors?

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Yu. See my edit to the end of the post with code of what I've tried and the error it throws.

Comment: Ah! So it's a syntax problem. Take a look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/msAtD89dn4DndMtxukkgkP/2 . Is that looks like something you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Ahhh yes! I was grasping for how to write the second part. Incidentally, after I'd edited the original post I started fiddling with views: I basically made Part I and Part II each their own view, and then wrote out a more n00b-looking join to put them together - and it worked! I was considering posting it to answer my own question, but I'd prefer to give you credit for your answer. Definitely post it as an answer!

Comment: " I basically made Part I and Part II each their own view" - when CTE appeared in DB2 (IIRC) they were called as "temporary views" - so you were very close to solution with CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a syntax issue.

OP already had all needed parts:

- Part I and Part II subqueries were already implemented
- it was defined how to join them

The only problem was a struggle with syntax.

I suppose this form would be the most readable:

```sql
WITH PartI AS(
 select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.service_date,
    h.principal_problem_cd,
    h.problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.auto_claims_line_items as l
JOIN claims.auto_claims_general h on l.claim_id = h.claim_id
UNION ALL
select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.entry_date as service_date,
    NULL as principal_problem_cd,
    NULL as problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.motorcycle_claims_line_items as l 
), 
PartII AS (
  select customer_dob,
       customer_id,
       customer_gender_cd,
       customer_zip_cd,
       customer_combined_id
from customer."Customer"  m
JOIN customer.customer_combined_crosswalk c on m.customer_id = c.customer_id 
) 
SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        PartI P1
        LEFT JOIN PartII P2 
          ON P1.customer_combined_id = P2.customer_combined_id;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/msAtD89dn4DndMtxukkgkP/2

Comment: I'm noticing something now after running the code: the resulting dataset contains about 3x as many rows as I'd expected -- about 300,000. "Part I", run by itself, yields a table with 100k rows, and "Part II" alone yields a table with 3k rows. I only intended to get a result with the same 100k as Part I. Any insight? No worries if not, I'm happy to make that its own question. Thanks Alex.

Comment: First obvious is to look if `JOIN customer.customer_combined_crosswalk ` contains more than 1 row per `customer_id`. Take a look on `SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) FROM customer_combined_crosswalk GROUP BY customer_id HAVING COUNT(*) >1`

Comment: Another part: look if there are duplicates in PartI: `SELECT customer_combined_id, COUNT(*) from PartI GROUP BY customer_combined_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: Thanks, that revealed the issue: there's only supposed to be ~1k rows in "Part II", and there's ~3k! That means each `customer_combined_id` is appearing in the right-hand-side (RHS) table nearly 3 times. This meant that for each `customer_combined_id` in Part I, the `LEFT JOIN` was finding 3 matches or so, tripling the final row count. I'm gonna strip out the duplicate `customer_combined_id`'s and rerun the solution with a new 'Part II". Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Yu's answer is better, but I wanted to post this because a) it also works and b) shows a neat use for views in SQL.

Take the first part, and make a view of it by adding a single line of `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` before the first `select`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW clms AS
select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.service_date,
    h.principal_problem_cd,
    h.problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.auto_claims_line_items as l
JOIN claims.auto_claims_general h on l.claim_id = h.claim_id
UNION ALL
select
    l.customer_combined_id,
    l.claim_id,
    l."Part_Cd",
    l.entry_date as service_date,
    NULL as principal_problem_cd,
    NULL as problem_code_vers_flag
from claims.motorcycle_claims_line_items as l
```

Next, do the same for the second part:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cstmr AS
select m.customer_dob,
       m.customer_id,
       m.customer_gender_cd,
       m.customer_zip_cd,
       c.customer_combined_id
from customer."Customer" m
JOIN customer.customer_combined_crosswalk c on m.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

Finally, do a SQL 101-level simple join of the two views:

```
select *
from clms
join cstmr m on clms.customer_combined_id = customer_combined_id
```

I bumped into this answer after posting the problem and was happy to find a (somewhat) elegant solution myself.

Comment: It's absolutely valid solution for ancient engines that does not support CTEs. E.g. MSSQL 2000 or ancient Oracles. But you could use subqueries in the same way as you do with views.